# How to uninstall a component in embarcadero delphi 2010?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Yesterday, i have installed the TPing component which are designed for Delphi 7 in my embarcadero delphi 2010, but today i noticed that this component causes my application to crash due to an access violation error, when i click on the Start button.

I searched in the internet for the most common reasons which causes the access voilation problems, i found i faw reasons which includes installing a package/component which are not compatible with the current version. And therfore, i guess that this component is the reason of my Access violation error.

Please could you help me on how to uninstall a componenet / package . And restore the backup which are made automatically during installation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Close all projects in IDE, click `Component -> Install packages ..` from the main menu, find the package that contains your component, select it and click `Remove` button.

Comment: And then make sure the path has been removed from Project|Options|Directories and Conditionals and Tools|Environment Options|Libraries, so the wrong units don't end up compiling into your projects by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for Borland Delphi 7 ...
Any way.. I found an option.

Main Menu > Project > Remove from project > 
It will open project manager
Select appropriate project 
select pas file
click on remove..